# Why can't you call a 'No Parking' sign self-evident? Why can't a fact be self-explanatory?

Tags: difference

> [This [No Parking] sign is self-explanatory. The sign itself explains why it was put there - to prohibit parking in that location. We wouldn't call the sign self-evident because the sign isn't a truth, idea or function.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/102403)

##### Why wouldn't we call a No Parking sign self-evident??? Why can't this sign be a truth, idea or function?

Consider the sign [like the one below](https://houston.culturemap.com/news/city-life/04-30-13-fake-no-parking-signs-crop-up-all-over-houston-illegal-signs-prove-to-be-an-effective-scare-tactic). Sign lays down the law, and constitutes the truth on the subject of parking. Sign conveys in text, and illustrates, the idea of no parking. Sign has at least 3 functions — to forbid parking, convey no parking to readers, and convey towing as the penalty of parking.

> [A fact can be self-evident. A fact cannot be self-explanatory.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/102475)

#### Why not self-explanatory? Consider a fact like  [1 + 1  = 2](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/8738).

This is self-evident, if you can behold that adding one object (e.g. finger, toe) to another  sums to 2. This is self-explanatory because if you can't see this fact — then you can physically take one object, another object, and count them!

[image]

Comment: This is about how words are used. Different words are used in different contexts to describe different things. That's just how language works.

Comment: @StuartF your comment feels too vague. how does it answer my questions?

Comment: @user35395 The fun thing about comments is that they don't have to answer anything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a no-parking sign over the precipice, in the water, or at any other site where it's physically impossible to park a vehicle, you may call the sign self-evident. The property on the photograph seems ordinary, why shouldn't I park there? Because the sign says so. It explains why it was mounted there (to prohibit parking), thus it's self-explanatory. Is it self-evident? No. What is special about this place? Why is authorisation required?

To call `1 + 1 = 2` self-explanatory, you would have to set the context, and settle on the definitions. What is addition? What are 1 and 2? What base system do we use? (Binarily, `1 + 1 = 0b10`). Even if you did that, you would just get a mathematical statement that has to be proved.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand the concepts of a (road) sign and parking, then it is self evidently a parking sign.  (That is, the fact that it is a parking sign is self evident.)  What it signifies may or [may not](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UeHcZnvUIeE) be self evident or even self explanatory.  For example, in this instance, what an "unauthorised vehicle" is is not explained.